# Python asyncio coroutine access one shared object

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, shared-memory, coroutine

I am writing a simple MMO game using asyncio and I have got a problem with shared memory. I have got an object that contains every needed information about game like mobs positions, players positions, items etc.
I want to share this object with every coroutine that handles connection with client, but I have no idea how to do it. I was using something like this:

```
global singleton
singleton = pack(GameInformationsObject())
```

Where pack() is:

```
def pack(objectToPack):
    tmp = pickle.dumps(objectToPack)
    array = multiprocessing.Array('i', tmp)
    return array
```

And i unpack it with:

```
def unpack(unpackIt):
    tmp = array.array('B', unpackIt[:])
    obj = pickle.loads(tmp.tostring())
    return obj
```

Which works but it is so slow, that i can send update with data once in a second, with:

```
tmp = unpack(singleton)
pack = tmp.getOnlyWhatThisClientCanSee()
try:
   package = pickle.dumps(pack)
   socket.send(package)
except (BrokenPipeError, IOError):
   #client disconnected, save position in database
```

Are there some stupid errors that I made, better ways to do this or way to make it efficient?

Greetings,
Dunedain

Comment: How about sending notifications via [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#condition) objects?

Comment: AFAIK, pickle is a little bit slow while packing the huge data. I use protobuf and zmq to communicate between different process, it's way more faster.